# Does DFS ls command read namespace from fsimage file or both(edit log & fsimage) ?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to hadoop. I know that hdfs will not create directory physically instead of maintain namespace. We can list directory using FS command. My question is will ls command read from fsimage file alone or edit log file also? Because recent directory changes will not exist in fsimage file.

Answer (score 1):

All HDFS questions are answered by the namenode using it's in-memory image of the file system. This does not correspond to neither fsimage nor the log. Reading the fsimage and applying the log *should* reach the same state as the in-memory image of the namenode, true, but no process (other than namenode...) reads these files to determine HDFS state (eg. run a DFS command), everybody must ask the authoritative source: the [namenode](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NameNode). [Secondary namenode](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Secondary_NameNode), [checkpoint node](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Checkpoint_Node)  or [backup node](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Backup_Node) do read these files, but they don't answer any DFS command.

Comment: Thanks. if I delete fsimage or edit file(just for testing purpose), still I could able to see directory listing using dfs command.Am I right?

Comment: If you corrupt your system intentionally, for whatever purpose, the results are undefined. Any result can be observed: dfs command may succeed, may fail, may succeed with incorrect results. Anything.